# flutter_barcode_scanner dosn't work in releasebuild

Tags: android, flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

I am using the flutter_barcode_scanner (version 1.0.2) in my app.

When I do a debug build, the scanner works fine. (flutter build apk --debug)

When I do a release build I get no result (Flutter Build Apk - No-Shrink) & (Flutter Build Apk - Release).

I'm using Flutter version 2.0.3

Comment: Have you added all permissions

Comment: I use the camera and the internet permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />